# sklearn ColumnTransformer creates new columns in output when there are overlapping columns between steps

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I need to process some dataframe columns in different steps using [ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html). 
The first step process the date columns (timestamp) imputing missing values and the second step applies scaling to all the numeric columns (including the dates columns). In output I get a number of columns which is the sum of the numeric columns and the dates columns, but the dates columns are a subset of the numeric columns so this is not correct.

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder

dates_columns = ['ts_1', 'ts_2']
numeric_columns = ['ts_1', 'ts_2', 'n_1', 'n_2']

column_transformer = ColumnTransformer([
    ('imputer_dates', SimpleImputer(strategy='median', missing_values=0), date_columns),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler(), numeric_columns)
])

X_transformed = column_transformer.fit_transform(X)
print(X_transformed.shape) # Got 6 columns, but it should be 4
```

How to fix this?